# Firefox extension Load page in popap

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want a firefox extension, so when you click on icon it opens popup and loads my page inside of the popup.

I have next issue. I need when I click on extension icon to pick up URL of the current tab and load my page in popup with sending that URL as query string.

So when you click on icon it opens popup and loads page like "http://example.com?url={current-URL}"

The issue is that it loads my page in popup once, and next time I click on extension it opens already rendered popup. Here is the code I am using:

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "My button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
    width: 700,
    height: 543,
    contentURL: 'http://example.com?url='+ tabs.activeTab.url,
    contextMenu : true,
    onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

So what I want is each time I click on extension icon it loads my page in panel AGAIN, not just show already rendered page. Is this possible and how I can do this, any help?

Answer (score 1):

Panel's `contentURL` property has a setter defined, so changing the url is as simple as:

```
function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
   panel.contentURL = 'http://example.com?url='+ tabs.activeTab.url,
   panel.show({
    position: button
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work really fine. Opening panel when new tab is active it reloads page from the URL but with 1-2 sec of delay. It first shows already rendered page, then after 1-2 secs it reloads it. And for opening-closing panel under the same tab doesn't reload the page at all, always shows first time rendered. I need it to every time when panel is displayed to render page again. Chrome extension works really fine with this

Comment: Is it possible to set the page before clicking on the button?

Comment: It is possible, however the page will always stay open when the popup is hidden. Well, technically the iframe stays the same. This is so you can still communicate with the page and don't have to care whether or not the page is loaded. Workaround would be to always set the url to "about:blank" when closing the panel.

Comment: @humanoid I torgot to tag the message to him. I wanted to ask him whether it acceptable for him to change the url of panel on new tab open and on url change. Anyway thanks for your detailed response, this helps aswell!